# IRCUtils: Cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer interface

Tags: python, interface, buffer, irc, python-2to3

I'm playing about with the idea of making a simple IRC bot. It seems like there is a variety of Python software written for this purpose, with varying feature sets and varying degrees of complexity. I found [this package](http://dev.guardedcode.com/docs/ircutils/index.html#) which seems to have a pretty user-friendly interface, and installed it.

I first ran into the problem that the package seems to have been written without Python 3 in mind. I ran the 2to3 converter tool on it and was subsequently able to import the package. However, in trying to replicate the example from the documentation, I get the error in the question title. Here is my script, with the name of the channel removed:

```
from ircutils import bot

class hambot (bot.SimpleBot):
    def on_channel_message (self, event):
        if event.message == 'go away hambot':
            self.quit('Goodbye.')

def main ():
    hb = hambot('hambot')
    hb.connect('irc.synirc.org', channel = '(channel name removed)')
    hb.start()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Here's the result I get when I try to run it. The first exception makes reference only to a script called `asynchat.py`, which seems to be a part of Python itself rather than a part of the IRCUtils package, so I am a bit lost as to what the problem might be.

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hambot
>>> hambot.main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asynchat.py", line 243, in initiate_send
    data = buffer(first, 0, obs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asynchat.py", line 56, in buffer
    memoryview(obj)
TypeError: cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer inter
face

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Docs\programs\python\hambot\hambot.py", line 11, in main
    hb.start()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ircutils\client.py", line 271, in start
    self.conn.start()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\ircutils\connection.py", line 115, in star
t
    asyncore.loop(map=self._map)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asyncore.py", line 216, in loop
    poll_fun(timeout, map)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asyncore.py", line 162, in poll
    write(obj)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asyncore.py", line 95, in write
    obj.handle_error()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asyncore.py", line 91, in write
    obj.handle_write_event()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asyncore.py", line 466, in handle_write_event
    self.handle_write()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asynchat.py", line 194, in handle_write
    self.initiate_send()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\asynchat.py", line 245, in initiate_send
    data = first.more()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'more'
>>>
```

There is one question already on StackOverflow relating to this error message, but the accepted answer states that in that case it relates to a package called "gevent", which as far as I can tell is not even installed on my machine, so I do not think it pertains to this.

Comment: `2to3` is not a one-size-fits-all tool; it makes it possible to write code that'll run well on Python 2 and can be translated automatically to Python 3, but it will not automatically and correctly translate *arbitrary* python 2 code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because of the change to the way strings work in Python 3. The following bug may be relevant: http://bugs.python.org/issue12523

The IRCUtils library may be made to work as follows: in addition to running the 2to3 script, make the following changes to `connection.py`:

```
Line 31: change from
    self.set_terminator("\r\n")
to
    self.set_terminator(b"\r\n")

Line 63: change from
    data = "".join(self.incoming)
to
    data = "".join([x.decode('utf8', 'replace') for x in self.incoming])

Line 96: change from
    self.push("%s %s\r\n" % (command.upper(), " ".join(params)))
to
    self.push(bytes("%s %s\r\n" % (command.upper(), " ".join(params)), 'utf8'))
```